# Jquery Colorbox Dotted Lines & Close Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I'm using JQuery Colorbox to load up when the page opens and it's working fine except that there is a dotted line around the box and also, the close button (circle) appears to be over the top of a beveled box:

[image: Dotted Lines]

Any ideas why this is and how to prevent it?

Also I'd like to prevent the box from closing when clicking anywhere outside of the box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your html so I will assume that your  tags might be getting styling inherited from another style rule?

If not, then you can just inspect it and see where the embossed effect styling is coming from and remove it yourself.

For clicking outside the box you can find out the background filler div and add a jQuery preventDefault() to its click function or you can just edit the plug-in's JS.

Answer (score 0):

The close button is a button element and it looks like it is inheriting the default button border style because no border style has been set for it in your CSS.

You are probably using an old version of Colorbox's CSS with a newer version of the script file, which now uses button elements for controls.  You can fix this by using the current css file for Colorbox or by going into your CSS and removing the default border style for that button element.  Example:

```
#cboxClose { border: 0; }
```